# css3 animations/transitions

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I wonder if css3 animations is applicable for window scroll? In jquery for example you use something like:

```
$(window).animate({scrollTop: '+=200'}, 300, function() { });
```

So my question is if it's possible to do something similar with css3, and therefor use the advantages of the hardware accelerated css3 animations? Is it possible to animate a scroll area with css3?

Comment: @emiloson , i don't think so .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not applicable to scroll. CSS has no such concept as scroll position.

Comment: Hmm, ok, that's a shame isn't it. Would be very nice to be able to animate scrollTo behavior with the benefits of css3...

Comment: You should be able to transition / animate the whole body up and down (or a container div), but yeah, otherwise not possible with CSS.